# How to Get Script on Atom to Print Object Values without print() for Python?

Tags: python

I'm getting acquainted with Atom and its script package so I can run commands off the go. Right now I'm trying to run this code:

```
data = ['ACME', 50, 91.1, (2012, 12, 21)]
name, shares, price, date = data
print(name)
```

However, the book can get the value of name to print just by typing:

```
name
```

I would like to be able to do this, because when I run the book's code, script runs the code with no output. Also, is there a way to get script to run each single line I'm currently on when pressing Ctrl+Shift+B (like Ctrl+Enter in R Studio?)

Comment: change it to tuple. `data = ('ACME', 50, 91.1, (2012, 12, 21))`

Answer (score 0):

Your book is probably running Python in [interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html), you can access it by typing `python -i` or just `python` in your terminal.

The reason typing `name` works in interactive mode is because in that environment, the Interpreter prints the `repr` of each line, nothing if it returned `None`.

If you already wrote your code into a file, you can still run it using interactive mode by running the following:

```
python -i < file.py
```

---

When you actually want to see the data, you should use `print()` as it outputs the `str` of the value and Python files are not automatically ran in interactive mode.

<sub>I don't use Atom so I can't suggest an "Atomic" solution.</sub>

Comment: I decided to use a terminal package with atom, and it works real nicely. Thanks!